# Is there a way to automatically add dependencies to requirements.txt as they are installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requirements.txt

Similar to how Node.js automatically adds dependencies to `package-lock.json`, is there a way I can automatically add requirements to my `requirements.txt` file for Python?

Comment: Are you expecting `pip install` to append the package into requirements.txt? Or another trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned Node.js specifically, the Python project that comes closest to what you're looking for is probably [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Blurb [from the Pipenv documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv):

> Pipenv is a dependency manager for Python projects. If you're familiar with Node.js's `npm` or Ruby’s `bundler`, it is similar in spirit to those tools. While pip can install Python packages, Pipenv is recommended as it’s a higher-level tool that simplifies dependency management for common use cases.

It's quite a popular package among developers as the [many stars on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/stargazers) attest.

Alternatively, you can use a "virtual environment" in which you only install the external dependencies that your project needs. You can either use the [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) module from the standard library or the [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io) package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org), which offers certain additional features (that you may or may not need). With either of those, you can then use Python's (standard) package manager Pip to [update the requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze):

```
pip freeze >requirements.txt
```

This is the "semi-automatic" way, so to speak. Personally, I prefer to do this manually. That's because in a typical development environment ("virtual" or not), you also install packages that are only required for development tasks, such as running tests or building the documentation. They don't need to be installed along with your package on end-user machines, so shouldn't be in `requirements.txt`. Popular packaging tools such as [Flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io) and [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs) manage these ["extra dependencies"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies) separately, [as does Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux you can create an alias like this:

```
alias req='pip3 freeze > ~/requerments.txt'
```

And then when you want to install new package use this command:

```
pip3 install <package> | req
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, [to-requirements.txt](https://pypi.org/project/to-requirements.txt/) is what you need:

```sh
pip install to-requirements.txt
requirements-txt setup
```

After that installed packages will be appended to `requirements.txt`. And uninstalled packages will be removed.
It might require root access if you install it on system-wide Python interpreter. Add `sudo` if it failes.